# How to select this datepicker button with Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

Ok, so I am trying to clicking on this next button on this test automation test page (https://www.phptravels.net/). Picture:
[See the button and DOM here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvAmX.png)

I tried locating it by XPATH:

```
current_browser.find_element_by_xpath("//th[@class='next']").click()
```

and by XPATH but waiting for it to load:

```
WebDriverWait(current_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//th[@class="next"]'))).click()
```

Despite my efforts it always throws `elementNotVisibleException`:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

How should I target and click this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that there are 21 `th` tags with a class of `next` within the page. It seems like there are 7 datepicker dropdowns, each containing an option for days, months and years - your current XPath will always pick up the first one that it finds in the page, which is the datepicker for selecting the check-in date by day (which is why you are getting an `ElementNotVisibleException`).

From your screenshot it seems like you are trying to select by month, in which case your XPaths can be as follows...

Check-in:
`//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][1]/div[@class='datepicker-months']//th[@class='next']`

Check-out:
`//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][2]/div[@class='datepicker-months']//th[@class='next']`

If you are hoping to reference the different datepickers, then you can swap out `months`, `days` and `years` in these XPaths as appropriate - I hope this helps!

Comment: It does works like a charm thank you. This way of selecting also includes a lot of neat things I was not aware of - such as selecting sub-elements by referring to it by index ([1]) and using sub-location by entering another locator after a single "/". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the xpath generated by Chrome Dev Tools? It gives me this xpath: "/html/body/div[9]/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th[3]" and it seems to be working

Comment: I would like to avoid using absolute XPATH, I found them really fragile.